# PersistenceUnit vs PersistenceContext

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, persistence, entitymanager

In few project I have been successfully using

```
@PersistenceUnit(unitName = "MiddlewareJPA")
EntityManagerFactory emf;
...
EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
```

to obtain `EntityManager` for Database connection, but some days ago I was trying to move my project to `Jboss EAP 6.2` and it couldn't create `EntityManager`. I was googling it and I found that I should try change `@PersistenceUnit` to

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "MiddlewareJPA")
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

to obtain *EntityManager*. It worked but I don't know why. What is the difference bettween `PersistenceUnit` and `PersistenceContext`? What are pros and cons of each one? Where should we be using one of them?

Comment: Consider adopting the CDI spec (new in JEE 6) to do your dependency injections so you have a more "universal" way of doing it in stead of a big pile of API/framework specific annotations. That doesn't really provide support for entity manager injections out of the box in JEE 6 itself, but there are documented ways of dealing with that. http://www.mastertheboss.com/cdi/cdi-and-jpa-tutorial

Comment: As an addition to the available answers: here is an extremely useful article that can also help answer the OP's questions: [JPA Concepts](http://tomee.apache.org/jpa-concepts.html)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I don't know how it works exactly in the Java EE, but in Spring, when you specify `@PersistenceContext` annotation, it injects `EntityManager`. Where does it get `EntityManager`? It is wrong to create one `EntityManager` for the whole application lifetime by calling `EntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()`. So instead a special implementation of `EntityManager` interface is used and instantiated directly. It has an internal mutable thread-local reference to a *real* `EntityManager`. Implementations of methods just redirect calls to this *real* `EntityManager`. And there is a servlet listener, that before each request obtain `EM` by calling `EMF.createEntityManager()` and assign it to that inner reference of special `EM`. Also this listener manages transactions by calling `getTransaction().begin()`, `.commit()` and `.rollback()` on the *real* `EM`. It is very simplified description of performed work. And I believe, that JEE container does the same thing, as Spring does.

In general case it is better to inject `EntityManager`, because with `EntityManagerFactory` and `@PersistenceUnit` you should create/destroy `EntityManager` every time by hands and manage transactions too.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#orm-jpa-dao The injected EntityManager is Spring-managed

Answer (score 80):

`PersistenceUnit` injects an `EntityManagerFactory`, and `PersistenceContext` injects an `EntityManager`. It's generally better to use `PersistenceContext` unless you really need to manage the `EntityManager` lifecycle manually.

Comment: But if we have more than one persistance units then is there a way other than managing the EntityManagerFactory?

Comment: To answer @raj240's question, we can inject the entity manager using the respective persistence unit's name

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "MiddlewareJPA")

Answer (score 17):

`EntityManager` obtained via `@PersistenceContext` is called Container Managed `EntityManager` as container will be responsible for managing "`EntityManager`". `EntityManager` obtained via `@PersistenceUnit` / `entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()` is managed in the application by the developer. (for e.g. managing lifecycle of `EntityManager`, releasing the resources acquired by `EntityManager`, etc.).

Comment: Here is good article for J2EE https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/entity-context.html