# Can @PersistenceUnit and @PersistenceContext be used in the same application

Tags: spring, hibernate

I've inherited an application and the persistence.xml has this:

```
    <persistence-unit name="nxPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>someDSName</non-jta-data-source>
```

The code uses @PersistenceUnit and @PersistenceContext but I'm reading the for transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" only @PersistenceUnit should be used. The app appears to be functioning properly and the majority of the time @PersistenceContext is used so I'm confused as to why they didn't use transaction-type="JTA".

I'm reluctant to change working code but we have noted performance issues so I'm wondering if this mixed usage can be contributing to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's completely independent notions.

1. As for transaction types. As [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.15.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) says

> Typically you need an application server’s JTA capability only if your application needs to handle transactions across multiple resources, which is not a requirement for many applications. Many high-end applications use a single, highly scalable database (such as Oracle RAC) instead.

2. As for `@PersistenceUnit` and `@PersistenceContext`.

When you need to use `EntityManagerFactory`, you should use `@PersistenceUnit`.
When you need to use `EntityManager`, you should use `@PersistenceContext`.

By the way, JPA 2 allow you to obtain an `EntityManagerFactory` from  an existing `EntityManager`. See method `EntityManager.getEntityManagerFactory()`

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21038706/persistenceunit-vs-persistencecontext).